# Rspec: How to expect the href link which is inside the table

Tags: rspec, capybara

```
      expect(page). to have_xpath("//table//tbody//tr[1]//td[4][contains(href(), edit_data_source_group_path(data_source_group_1.id))]")
```

I need to expect href "edit_data_source_group_path(data_source_group_1.id)" which is inside the table and I tried above code.

I am sure that I am not passing proper expression under contains
And go below error 
 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError:
       Given xpath expression "//table//tbody//tr[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQZV2.png)//td[4][contains(href(), edit_data_source_group_path(data_source_group_1.id))]" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.

I have also attached a snap shot of the Table for which i need solution
Could someone help me out how to expect proper href which is inside Table[image]

Answer (score 1):

First you should stop trying to do everything in one XPath. It makes things highly brittle, tough to read, and is just a pain. Assuming there's only one table on the page you can do something like this

```
cell = page.find(:xpath, './/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]')
expect(cell).to have_link(href: edit_data_source_group_path(data_source_group_1.id))
```

or using CSS instead of XPath

```
cell = page.find('tbody > tr:first-child > td:nth-child(4)')
expect(cell).to have_link(href: edit_data_source_group_path(data_source_group_1.id))
```

If there was more than one table on the page you could either scope to the correct table or you could do this with a filter block

```
expect(page).to have_xpath('.//tbody/tr[1]/td[4]') do |cell|
  cell.has_link?(href: edit_data_source_group_path(data_source_group_1.id))
end
```

If there's only one link on the page to that specific location you could also reverse the process with something like

```
link = page.find_link(href: edit_data_source_group_path(data_source_group_1.id))
expect(link).to match_css('td:nth-child(4) a')
```

Note - all XPaths starting with `.//` - that's important - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#beware-the-xpath--trap - and just one more reason not to use XPaths unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in xpath, you shouldn't  use href(), use just href, try something like that: 
    expect(page). to have_xpath("//table//tbody//tr[1]//td[4][contains(href, edit_data_source_group_path(data_source_group_1.id))]")